# Clojure - Speed up large file processing

Tags: clojure, large-files

I need to read large file (~1GB), process it and save to db. My solution looks like that:

**data.txt**

format: `[id],[title]\n`

```
1,Foo
2,Bar
...
```

**code**

```
(ns test.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.string :refer [split]]))

(defn parse-line
  [line]
  (let [values (split line #",")]
    (zipmap [:id :title] values)))

(defn run
  []
  (with-open [reader (io/reader "~/data.txt")]
    (insert-batch (map parse-line (line-seq reader)))))

; insert-batch just save vector of records into database
```

But this code does not work well, because it first parse all lines and then send them into database.

I think the ideal solution would be `read line -> parse line -> collect 1000 parsed lines -> batch insert them into database -> repeat until there is no lines`. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One suggestion:

- Use [line-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) to get a lazy sequence of lines,
- use map to parse each line,

(so far this matches what you are doing)

- use [partition-all](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-all) to partition your lazy sequence of parsed lines into batches, and then
- use insert-batch with [doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) to write each batch to the database.

And an example:

```
(->> (line-seq reader)
     (map parse-line)
     (partition-all 1000)
     (#(doseq [batch %] 
       (insert-batch batch))))
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much. I see that I have a problem understanding lazy sequences. Do you know about any good sources which can help me to better understand it?

Comment: What if you wanted to parallelize processing the partitions? any `pmap` equivalent for `doseq` or other recommended idiom for managing a bunch of agents as executors?

Comment: Since clojure 1.7 you can replace the last part with simply (run! Insert-batch). Also it should be insert-batch! as it modifies state (in db).